# Get the full path of the file returned from a glob expansion

Tags: bash, shell

How to echo the path of a file, found with a wildcard:

File path: `/DIRECTORY_random_number/myFile`

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE='DIRECTORY_'*'/myFile'
if [ -f $FILE ]; then
   echo "this is the full path of this file..."
fi
```

Comment: You can use `echo $file` after your first `echo` to get full path

Comment: As simple as that, post it in answer. Why does `echo "$FILE"` isn't getting the full path but only the variable with the wildcard?

Comment: `echo "$FILE"` doesn't work because quoting prevents glob expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a variable is not the best way to go about this. Also the globs are not expanded when used with single/double quote. Use an array and also if its a single file you are looking for, the full path can be retrieved using array expansion with `*`

```
shopt -s nullglob
filePath=(/DIRECTORY_*/newfile)

if (( "${#filePath[@]}" )); then
    printf 'Matching file name found as %s\n' "${filePath[*]}"
fi
```

If you are using the bourne again shell, `bash`, enable and extended shell option `nullglob`, so that empty expansions are not part of the array.

This approach is far better than doing an unquoted variable expansion which would undergo Word-Splitting of your file names, if it contains special characters in the names.

Answer (score 1):

You can press a `for` loop to do this, especially in POSIX shells that don't have arrays.

```
for f in DIRECTORY_*/myFile; do
    if [ -f "$f" ]; then
        ...
    fi
    break
done
```

Whether you need the `break` statement is a judgement call. Your *intention* is that the pattern only matches a single file, but can you *guarantee* that? If you can, the `break` isn't necessary. Of course, if it *does* match more than one file, how do you know that the first match is the one you actually want? Generally, it's a bad idea to make assumptions about your file system like this. *Know* which file it is you are looking for rather than assuming there is a unique match for your pattern.